# Append directory name to the end of the files and move them

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am finding some files in a directory using this command:

```
find /Users/myname -type f
```

output is:

```
/Users/myname/test01/logs1/err.log
/Users/myname/test01/logs1/std
/Users/myname/test01/logs2/std
/Users/myname/test02/logs2/velocity.log
/Users/myname/test03/logs3/err.log
/Users/myname/test03/logs3/invalid-arg
```

I need to move this files to a different directory by appending the **test** directory name to the end of the files. Like below:

```
err.log-test01
std-test01
std-test01
velocity.log-test02
err.log-test03
invalid-arg-test03
```

I am trying with the cut command but not getting the desired output.

```
find /Users/myname -type f | cut -d'/' -f6,4
```

plus, I also need to move the files to a different directory. I guess a suitable way could be there using sed command, but I am not proficient with sed. How this can be achieved in an efficient way?

Comment: I don't really understand the requirement "..move these files to a different directory by appending..". How can you move by appending? Or do you mean to say that you wish to rename the files (appending -test at the end of the filename) and then move them to a new directory?

Comment: Do you understand in your example that `/Users/myname/test01/logs1/std` is overwritten with `/Users/myname/test01/logs2/std` creating `std-test01`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it from the dst to the `dst_dir` appending the directory, using `awk`, and the target name would be `awk -F/ '{print $5 "-" $4}'`. The full command could be as simple as:

```
for i in `find . -type f`
   do mv $i /dst_dir/`echo $i| awk -F/ '{print $5 "-" $4}' `
done
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks a lot ! just a correction it is {print $6 "-" $4} :)

Answer (score 2):

You can let `find` create the `mv` command, use sed to modify it and then have it run by the shell:

```
find /Users/myname -type f -printf "mv %p /other/dir/%f\n" |
           sed 's,/\(test[0-9]*\)/\(.*\),/\1/\2-\1,' | sh
```

This assumes there are no spaces in any argument, otherwise liberally add `'` or `"`. Also run it without the final `| sh` to see what it actually wants to do. If you need to anchor the `test[0-9]*` pattern better you can include part of the left or right string to match:

`'s,myname/\(test[0-9]*\)/\(.*\),myname/\1/\2-\1,'`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things going on that you may want to use a helper script with `find` to insure you can validate the existence of the directory to move the files to, etc.. A script might take the form of:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $1 -o -z $2 ] && { # validate at least 2 arguments
    printf "error: insufficient input\n"
    exit 1
}

ffn="$1"                # full file name provided by find
newdir="$2"             # the target directory

# validate existence of 'newdir' or create/exit on failure
[ -d "$newdir" ] || mkdir -p "$newdir"
[ -d "$newdir" ] || { printf "error: uname to create '$newdir'\n"; exit 1; }

tmp="${ffn##*test}"     # get the test## number
num="${tmp%%/*}"

fn="${ffn##*/}"         # remove existing path from ffn

mv "$ffn" "${newdir}/${fn}-test${num}"  # move to new location

exit 0
```

Save it in a location where it is accessible under a name like `myscript` and make it executable (e.g. `chmod 0755 myscript`) You may also choose to put it in a directory within your path. You can then call the script for every file returned by `find` with:

```
find /Users/myname -type f -exec ./path/to/myscript '{}' somedir \;
```

Where `somedir` is the target directory for the renamed file. Helper scripts generally provide the ability to do required validation that would otherwise not be done in one-liners.